# configfs for HID, empty /sys/class/udc

Tags: hid

currently implementing a usb hid for mouse device. it is fully working as intended on the raspberry pi to emulate mouse movement on another pc. the implementation is similar to [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt).
[and this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.txt) detailed implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Configures USB gadgets per: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.txt

# Exit on first error.
set -e

# Echo commands to stdout.
set -x

# Treat undefined environment variables as errors.
set -u

modprobe libcomposite

# Adapted from https://github.com/girst/hardpass-sendHID/blob/master/README.md

cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir -p g1
cd g1

echo 0x1d6b > idVendor  # Linux Foundation
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB    # USB2

STRINGS_DIR="strings/0x409"
mkdir -p "$STRINGS_DIR"
echo "6b65796d696d6570690" > "${STRINGS_DIR}/serialnumber"
echo "tinypilot" > "${STRINGS_DIR}/manufacturer"
echo "Multifunction USB Device" > "${STRINGS_DIR}/product"

# Keyboard
KEYBOARD_FUNCTIONS_DIR="functions/hid.keyboard"
mkdir -p "$KEYBOARD_FUNCTIONS_DIR"
echo 1 > "${KEYBOARD_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/protocol" # Keyboard
echo 1 > "${KEYBOARD_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/subclass" # Boot interface subclass
echo 8 > "${KEYBOARD_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/report_length"
# Write the report descriptor
# Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/gadget_hid.html
D=$(mktemp)
echo -ne \\x05\\x01 >> "$D" # USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
echo -ne \\x09\\x06 >> "$D" # USAGE (Keyboard)
echo -ne \\xa1\\x01 >> "$D" # COLLECTION (Application)
echo -ne \\x05\\x07 >> "$D" #   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
echo -ne \\x19\\xe0 >> "$D" #   USAGE_MINIMUM (Keyboard LeftControl)
echo -ne \\x29\\xe7 >> "$D" #   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Right GUI)
echo -ne \\x15\\x00 >> "$D" #   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
echo -ne \\x25\\x01 >> "$D" #   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
echo -ne \\x75\\x01 >> "$D" #   REPORT_SIZE (1)
echo -ne \\x95\\x08 >> "$D" #   REPORT_COUNT (8)
echo -ne \\x81\\x02 >> "$D" #   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
echo -ne \\x95\\x01 >> "$D" #   REPORT_COUNT (1)
echo -ne \\x75\\x08 >> "$D" #   REPORT_SIZE (8)
echo -ne \\x81\\x03 >> "$D" #   INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
echo -ne \\x95\\x05 >> "$D" #   REPORT_COUNT (5)
echo -ne \\x75\\x01 >> "$D" #   REPORT_SIZE (1)
echo -ne \\x05\\x08 >> "$D" #   USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)
echo -ne \\x19\\x01 >> "$D" #   USAGE_MINIMUM (Num Lock)
echo -ne \\x29\\x05 >> "$D" #   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Kana)
echo -ne \\x91\\x02 >> "$D" #   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
echo -ne \\x95\\x01 >> "$D" #   REPORT_COUNT (1)
echo -ne \\x75\\x03 >> "$D" #   REPORT_SIZE (3)
echo -ne \\x91\\x03 >> "$D" #   OUTPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
echo -ne \\x95\\x06 >> "$D" #   REPORT_COUNT (6)
echo -ne \\x75\\x08 >> "$D" #   REPORT_SIZE (8)
echo -ne \\x15\\x00 >> "$D" #   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
echo -ne \\x25\\x65 >> "$D" #   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (101)
echo -ne \\x05\\x07 >> "$D" #   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
echo -ne \\x19\\x00 >> "$D" #   USAGE_MINIMUM (Reserved)
echo -ne \\x29\\x65 >> "$D" #   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Application)
echo -ne \\x81\\x00 >> "$D" #   INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
echo -ne \\xc0 >> "$D"      # END_COLLECTION
cp "$D" "${KEYBOARD_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/report_desc"

# Mouse
MOUSE_FUNCTIONS_DIR="functions/hid.mouse"
mkdir -p "$MOUSE_FUNCTIONS_DIR"
echo 0 > "${MOUSE_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/protocol"
echo 0 > "${MOUSE_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/subclass"
echo 5 > "${MOUSE_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/report_length"
# Write the report descriptor
D=$(mktemp)
echo -ne \\x05\\x01 >> "$D"      # USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
echo -ne \\x09\\x02 >> "$D"      # USAGE (Mouse)
echo -ne \\xA1\\x01 >> "$D"      # COLLECTION (Application)
                                 #   8-buttons
echo -ne \\x05\\x09 >> "$D"      #   USAGE_PAGE (Button)
echo -ne \\x19\\x01 >> "$D"      #   USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
echo -ne \\x29\\x08 >> "$D"      #   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 8)
echo -ne \\x15\\x00 >> "$D"      #   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
echo -ne \\x25\\x01 >> "$D"      #   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
echo -ne \\x95\\x08 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_COUNT (8)
echo -ne \\x75\\x01 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_SIZE (1)
echo -ne \\x81\\x02 >> "$D"      #   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                                 #   x,y absolute coordinates
echo -ne \\x05\\x01 >> "$D"      #   USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
echo -ne \\x09\\x30 >> "$D"      #   USAGE (X)
echo -ne \\x09\\x31 >> "$D"      #   USAGE (Y)
echo -ne \\x16\\x00\\x00 >> "$D" #   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
echo -ne \\x26\\xFF\\x7F >> "$D" #   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (32767)
echo -ne \\x75\\x10 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_SIZE (16)
echo -ne \\x95\\x02 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_COUNT (2)
echo -ne \\x81\\x02 >> "$D"      #   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                                 #   vertical wheel
echo -ne \\x09\\x38 >> "$D"      #   USAGE (wheel)
echo -ne \\x15\\x81 >> "$D"      #   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
echo -ne \\x25\\x7F >> "$D"      #   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
echo -ne \\x75\\x08 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_SIZE (8)
echo -ne \\x95\\x01 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_COUNT (1)
echo -ne \\x81\\x06 >> "$D"      #   INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
                                 #   horizontal wheel
echo -ne \\x05\\x0C >> "$D"      #   USAGE_PAGE (Consumer Devices)
echo -ne \\x0A\\x38\\x02 >> "$D" #   USAGE (AC Pan)
echo -ne \\x15\\x81 >> "$D"      #   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
echo -ne \\x25\\x7F >> "$D"      #   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
echo -ne \\x75\\x08 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_SIZE (8)
echo -ne \\x95\\x01 >> "$D"      #   REPORT_COUNT (1)
echo -ne \\x81\\x06 >> "$D"      #   INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
echo -ne \\xC0 >> "$D"           # END_COLLECTION
cp "$D" "${MOUSE_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/report_desc"

CONFIG_INDEX=1
CONFIGS_DIR="configs/c.${CONFIG_INDEX}"
mkdir -p "$CONFIGS_DIR"
echo 250 > "${CONFIGS_DIR}/MaxPower"

CONFIGS_STRINGS_DIR="${CONFIGS_DIR}/strings/0x409"
mkdir -p "$CONFIGS_STRINGS_DIR"
echo "Config ${CONFIG_INDEX}: ECM network" > "${CONFIGS_STRINGS_DIR}/configuration"

ln -s "$KEYBOARD_FUNCTIONS_DIR" "${CONFIGS_DIR}/"
ln -s "$MOUSE_FUNCTIONS_DIR" "${CONFIGS_DIR}/"
ls /sys/class/udc > UDC

chmod 777 /dev/hidg0
chmod 777 /dev/hidg1
```

however when implementing similar setup on a industrial pc running on linux, the same setup did not work. the main issue is that /sys/class/udc is empty. for the raspi, there is a udc fe980000.usb. for the industrial pc, it is not present. from various other forums. raspberry pi has this because of configuration of dtoverlay = dwc2 which is related to the driver. on the industrial pc it does not seem to have such driver.

the following has been explored/observed:

1. confirmed that kernel config setting of configfs is okay: CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_HID=y
2. modprobe configfs and libcomposite is working
3. ls /dev does not show hidg0 or hidg(number)
4. mounting to /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget works as intended as folder is created

the only issue/symptoms is /dev/hidg0 does not appear and thus cannot write to this. along with it, the udc is empty causing the bash script to fail at ls /sys/class/udc > UDC

for the industrial pc, it is running on
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
5.4.0-81-generic

apologies in advance as I am quite new to linux/ubuntu. any help is greatly appreciated.

edit for hardware:
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900T CPU @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:            13
CPU MHz:             899.790
CPU max MHz:         4400,0000
CPU min MHz:         800,0000
BogoMIPS:            4199.88
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:25ee Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

there are lots more com port and usb ports as compared to raspi

Comment: Whats the hardware platform you are running on? USB OTG is hardware specific, so even if it work on pi, your industrial PC might not support it

Comment: edited with the hardware specs. hardware wise, its more than the raspberry pi. not sure if its more likely to be a software issue

Comment: As PicoCreator already suggested: what is your industrial pc specific [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) hardware, and then driver? Search in the industrial pc specs (papers provided by the supplier/maker) for the name then the name for Linux support.

Comment: does that meant that if `modprobe g_hid` returns no such device, it is not supported or is it just that the driver is not yet installed

Comment: https://www.aaeon.com/en/p/fanless-embedded-box-pc-socket-type-boxer-6641#downloads

Comment: My guess is there's no support. Suggestions which might or might not be useful with two different kind of virtualization: https://blog.elastocloud.org/2016/06/linux-usb-gadget-application-testing.html , https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg137471.html . I wouldn't know how to use either.

Comment: hi thanks, for the support is it refering to the usb chipset or something else? tried `lspci` it gives Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10). is this the specific hardware that needs to be checked if otg is supported or something else

Comment: no I read the specs in your link: there are usb ports, none of them OTG

Comment: thanks for checking, is there a specific thing to look out for in the specs in order to see if OTG is supported? which part of the hardware should be searched for to check for with Linux support

Comment: This other system sold by the same vendor has the word "OTG" somewhere in its web page: https://www.aaeon.com/en/p/edge-ai-solutions-boxer-8150ai#p_spec

Comment: thanks looking it up in details. can it be understood that the code that requires "hidg" needs OTG supported hardware. and most OTG ports looks like a micro usb or a usb-c port and most of the time a usb-A port is not otg port unless stated otherwise

Comment: Unfortunately looking at the specs sheet, this device does not support USB OTG - so its probably a dead end here